# nginx link domain's subdirectory with subdomain

Tags: nginx

- example.com
- sub.example.com

When I access example.com/sub, I want to redirect sub.example.com, while browser address still remains example.com/sub

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Then you'll probably want to insert a virtualhost in your nginx configuration. Something like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.example.com;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $scheme://example.com/sub/$1 redirect;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work...(maybe due to another configs..)
Can I link example.com/sub with sub.example.com's index file then?

Comment: You may want to make sure that sub.example.com isn't listed as a server_name in any other vhost. Setting up a link: not sure. Please update your question: what OS, content for nginx.conf and "relevant included configs" (mostly your vhosts, not sure what you've customized on your own, ...). Some logs might help as well (`/var/log/nginx`)